# Which functions can be divided by a polynomial to give a polynomial remainder?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For which functions $f\colon\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, given a real polynomial $p(x)$, can we find a real polynomial $h(x)$ such that $deg(h(x))<deg(p(x))$ and:

$f(x)=q(x)p(x)+h(x)$ for some function $q\colon\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

I know that this is true when $f$ is a polynomial function, but does this hold for all functions on $\mathbb{R}$? Additionally given $f$ and $p(x)$ are $q$ and $h(x)$ unique?

Comment: Are we restricting $q(x)$ to be a polynomial as well? If so, then $f(x)$ must be a polynomial because it is the sum of a polynomial and the product of two polynomials, which is a polynomial.

Comment: Interesting.  Case $p(x) = x$ says: When can we find a constant $c$ so that $f(x) = xq(x)+c$? Or: when is $q(x) = \frac{f(x)-c}{x}$ allowed?  If we want $q$ to have a removable discontinuity at $0$, that means we want $f$ to be differentiable at $x=0$.  Probably asking that this work for all polynomials $p$ of degree $n$ will mean that $f$ is $n$ times differentiable.

Comment: No $q(x)$ is not a polynomial too, sorry I should have made that clearer.

Comment: @GEdgar Yeah this is the answer that I was looking for thanks. I think a weaker statement of yours would be that $f$ would have to be $n_k$ times differentiable at every $p_k$ root of $p$, where $n_k$ is the multiplicity of the root $p_k$. I may write my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also require that $q(x)$ be polynomial, then $f(x)$ must be.  The polynomials are closed under multiplication and addition.  The process of polynomial division will find $q,h$.  If you do not require $q(x)$ to be polynomial, you can use any $h(x)$ you want and as long as $p(x)$ is not zero you can solve for $q(x)$